# Converting fastq.gz to fasta. Having trouble installing ShortReads (Bioconductor)

Tags: r, bioconductor, file-conversion

I'm currently trying to use readFastq  with the ShortRead library. I have specified the version of Bioconductor I need (3.14) in order to run it in R version 4.1 (which is the one I'm currently using). I keep getting an error message saying:

```
> library(ShortRead)
Error in library(Shortread) : there is no package called 'ShortRead'
```

and also:

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'libhts.so.2': Operation not supported
make: *** [Makevars:28: populate-usrlib-dir] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘Rhtslib’
* removing ‘/home/jovyan/work/__dag_config__/R/libs/Rhtslib’
ERROR: dependency ‘Rhtslib’ is not available for package ‘Rsamtools’
* removing ‘/home/jovyan/work/__dag_config__/R/libs/Rsamtools’
ERROR: dependency ‘Rsamtools’ is not available for package ‘GenomicAlignments’
* removing ‘/home/jovyan/work/__dag_config__/R/libs/GenomicAlignments’
ERROR: dependencies ‘Rsamtools’, ‘GenomicAlignments’, ‘Rhtslib’ are not available for package ‘ShortRead’
* removing ‘/home/jovyan/work/__dag_config__/R/libs/ShortRead’
```

and

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘textshaping’
* removing ‘/opt/conda/envs/r/lib/R/library/textshaping’
* restoring previous ‘/opt/conda/envs/r/lib/R/library/textshaping’
* installing *source* package ‘ragg’ ...
** package ‘ragg’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
```

and lastly

```
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘ragg’
* removing ‘/opt/conda/envs/r/lib/R/library/ragg’
* restoring previous ‘/opt/conda/envs/r/lib/R/library/ragg’

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpgByRyT/downloaded_packages’
```

I would really appreciate som help with troubleshooting this or a "smarter" way to convert fastq.gz files to fasta files

The commands I've run so far are:

```
#Installing ShortRead package containing the readFastq function
if (!require("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
    install.packages("BiocManager")

BiocManager::install(version="3.14")
BiocManager::install("GenomeInfoDbData")
BiocManager::install("GenomeInfoDb")
BiocManager::install("ShortRead")


#Loading the library
library(ShortRead)
```

Some extra session information:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-conda-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /opt/conda/envs/r/lib/libopenblasp-r0.3.21.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8       
 [4] LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C              
[10] LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] BiocManager_1.30.19

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] compiler_4.1.1  fastmap_1.1.0   cli_3.4.1       htmltools_0.5.3 tools_4.1.1    
 [6] rstudioapi_0.14 yaml_2.3.6      rmarkdown_2.17  knitr_1.40      xfun_0.34      
[11] digest_0.6.30   rlang_1.0.6     evaluate_0.17
```

I do not understand why it won't install. I would it expect it to work when I have made sure to use the correct version

Comment: What is the output of `BiocManager::install("ShortRead")`? There should be an error message in there telling you what's wrong. Make sure to edit your question to include those details -- don't try to post it as a comment.

Comment: @MrFlick it was a mistake trying to post it as a comment. I have now added it in the main question. Thanks for letting me know.
The output of BiocManager::install("ShortRead") is too long to include though. So I have added the errors, but not everything else.